# How do I create a new column based on a rule for 2 columns in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 columns on a Google Spreadsheets file. First column is text and the second column is numbers (from 1 to 5, think as categories).

I would like to have a 3rd column from the words in the first row depending on the category. So I would like to have all the words that are "marked" "3" on 2nd column to be listed in column 3.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=query(A:B,"Select A where B=3")
```